# EF + AutoFac + async "The connection's current state is connecting"

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have a WebApi controller that has services injected by AutoFac in the OWIN Startup class

```
builder.Register(c => new MyEntities()).InstancePerRequest();
```

I have also tried

```
builder.Register(c => new MyEntities()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

In a controller action I call a service method to create a new record, pass the id created to an external api through HttpClient to get some more data, then update the new record with some return data.

```
[HttpPost, Route("")] 
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyControllerAction(MyModel model)
{
    var id = await _MyService.CreateNewThing(model.SomeId);
    var externalData = await CallExternalApiThroughHttpClient(id);
    await _MyService.UpdateNewThing(id, externalData);
    return Ok();
}
```

service code

```
public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    private MyEntities _context;

    public MyService(MyEntities context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<int> CreateNewThing(int someId)
    {
        var thing = new Thing
        {
            SomeId = someId
        };

        _context.Things.Add(thing);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return thing.Id;
    }

    public async Task UpdateNewThing(int id, string externalDataField)
    {
        var thing = await _context.Things.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == id);

            if (thing == null)
            {
                throw new ServiceNotFoundException("Thing " + transactionId + " not found");
            }

            thing.ExternalDataField= externalDataField;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

But I get an `InvalidOperationException` in UpdateNewThing `var thing = await _context.Things.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == id);`

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
```

It seems like I have to give up either injecting the context, async/await or use something like a contextfactory; unless anyone can spot something simple I have missed that would let me continue with this design.

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Can you show how you inject `_context` into the container? Is there a place where you dispose of the context? Do you call `CreateNewThing` and `UpdateNewThing` from the same method? Can you show a more complete code?

Comment: Added more code. I inject the context in the service class constructor. I am not disposing anywhere. CreateNewThing and UpdateNewThing are both in the same WebApi action. I need the new Id to send to the external api and then have to update the record with some return data; normally I wouldn't call my service like this.

Comment: I can't see an issue in your code. What happens if you don't do the web service call and instead test with some fake `externalData` data?

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. If you can't see any fundamental design flaws then I'll will work around this one.

Comment: What is the actual signature of the action?  It can't be "public MyControllerAction(MyModel model)" as you have.  Also, what is the lifetime of your IMyService, and can you perhaps show the code and declaration for that?  Does it fail every time with just a single invocation of that action?

Comment: sellotape, It was Task<IHttpActionResult> which I have now updated my question with the code. The service is InstancePerLifetimeScope.
I thought this code was working in a quick production test but it failed locally and I can't test in production again.

Comment: I assume that _MyService is injected on controller constructor. Is the external web service call using that same instance? Does it work if you remove injection and new up the instance on MyService constructor? Is the autofac web api extension configured in owin startup?

Comment: the external web call is just an httpclient post request. The service is injected in controller construction and the services registered in Owin Startup:  builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("MyProject.Core"))
                    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Comment: MyControllerAction() also has the async modifier, I assume?

Comment: yes, SO is not a great IDE! I should have copied and pasted.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine *in a single-threaded context*.  However, `DbContext` is not thread safe, and I suspect what is happening is you're executing `CreateNewThing()` on one thread, and the task scheduler is in this case executing `UpdateNewThing()` on a different thread.

Either way, a better metaphor is to use a context factory, which you inject into your `IMyService` in this case, and then for every `IMyService` method you create a new `MyEntities` context in a `using()` block.

`DbContext`'s are cheap to create and this is how they are intended to be used; long-lived contexts are almost always incorrect usage.

**Edit 1** - example context factory as requested.  I tend to implement a generic factory that can create multiple contexts, but that's probably moving outside the scope of this question.

```
public interface IMyEntitiesFactory
{
    MyEntities Create();
}

public class MyEntitiesFactory : IMyEntitiesFactory
{
    MyEntities IMyEntitiesFactory.Create()
    {
        return new MyEntities();
    }
}

// For use with unit tests; e.g. pass a mock object to the constructor.
public class TestMyEntitiesFactory : IMyEntitiesFactory
{
    private readonly MyEntities _value;

    public TestMyEntitiesFactory(MyEntities value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    MyEntities IMyEntitiesFactory.Create()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected but I would rather not use async than use it with a half understanding of what it's doing. I have seen a few examples of a contextfactory; all different. Do you have an example of one you have used before

Comment: There are lots of examples because you can do it pretty-much however you like as long as it creates a context.  I've added a fairly basic example to the answer.

Comment: ok, so just a simple factory - no fancy EF stuff for SaveChanges. Thanks

Comment: It should suffice for what you're doing; you just SaveChanges within each using() block.